# Firefox/Chomium always uses DejaVu fonts, even though system fonts are different

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, fonts, ubuntu-font-family

I have recently re-installed xubuntu 20.04.

I noticed that some fonts were *off*. so I opened the inspector in firefox dev-tools and noticed that the font used is `DejaVu`, although my system fonts are `IBM-plex` ones and all my gnome/xfce **respect** that setting.

It is just *Firefox* and *Chromium* that don't respect these settings. I have debugged a little bit and it seems:

Firefox/Chromium use the first font that it comes across Alphabetically, meaning that `DejaVu` is the first font that it seems to pick up.

I removed the `DejaVu` fonts to see if it will pick up my system fonts `IBM-Plex`, but to my surprise it used `Nimbus` which is not technically after `DejaVu` alphabetically.

I have read the fontconfig manual and tried changing the settings in `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/60-latin.conf` but is also does not seems to pick that up.

any pointer to help solve this problems?
I'm using firefox from the archives not snap version.

Edit: Oddly enough if I choose the `Ubuntu` font it seem to pick it up right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the `fc-match` command gives:

```
$ fc-match
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
```

You can create the file `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-prefer-ibm-plex.conf` and give it this contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <alias>
        <family>sans-serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>IBM Plex Sans</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

That will hopefully make a difference.